# make the block architecture in OS as in HADOOP

Tags: hadoop, operating-system, block

In HADOOP, the data is stored in blocks. In HADOOP, the blocks space are not wasted i.e. if any of the data is less than the specified block, the remaining space in the block is allocated for other file data blocks.

I mean (default block size 64MB), suppose a file A last block is of size 20MB now the remaining space is allocated for another file B of block 44MB. So none of the block space are wasted.

Whereas this is not the case in OS level. Every block in OS is specified as 4KB or 8KB. If any chunk of data is less then this size whole of the block space is occupied. **Can't we use the same architecture for blocks in OS level as of HADOOP**?

Comment: You can design and implement another file system (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems) that would use variable block allocation size and perhaps even super space-efficient similar to how some video codecs implement variable frame rate. But what is your question?